# Angular 9 BaseComponent with @Injectable()

Tags: angular, angular9

In Angular 8 I was able to create base components (classes the actual component inhert from) with an "@Injectable" attribute. The Angular 9 compiler tells me:

> The component YourComponent inherits its constructor from BaseComponent, but the latter does not have an Angular decorator of its own. Dependency injection will not be able to resolve the parameters of BaseComponent's constructor. Either add a @Directive decorator to BaseComponent, or add an explicit constructor to RoleSelectDialogComponent.

What is the Angular 9 way of doing these things now? This works but looks somehow hacky:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'baseComponent',
    template: 'no-ui'
})
```

Comment: Can you share your both component, seems you are not using base constructor, share more code

Comment: "YourComponent" has no constructor at all - worked with Angular9

Comment: What about the BaseComponent? if you want correct answer, always explain your problem in more detail & share the code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The clue is in the message

`Either add a @Directive decorator to BaseComponent`

Adding a @Directive() to it should do the trick.

I'm just going through an upgrade now, and my base component automatically has the @Directive() decorator added.

Comment: Is this the best practice? My BasComponent is not really a "Directive", is it?

Comment: It's recommended by the error message in Angular, so I would say so.

Comment: Seams to be correct answer: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35367#issuecomment-585136872

Comment: It will do the trick, but there is  a problem with TSLint now. Classes decorated as Directive should end with suffix "Directive". So this solution looks like a workaround

Answer (score 12):

This is probably going to hit more people now that Angular 10 is out and the warning is now an error.

> error NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated.
> Please add an explicit Angular decorator.

This blog entry shows some examples https://volosoft.com/blog/what-is-new-in-angular-10

---

In addition please note that 'Angular features' doesn't just mean dependency injection. Even the presence of `ngOnDestroy()` in your base class will trigger this.

I solved it by renaming `ngOnDestroy()` to `_ngOnDestroy()` and called it from the subclass on destruction of the actual `@Injectable()`. This seems a little dangerous if I were to ever subclass it again and forgot to call `_ngOnDestroy()` but I'm not sure I had much choice.

Comment: did you find any alternative till today ?

Comment: @LoganWlv unfortunately not. Only had it in a couple places

Answer (score 1):

This pattern has been deprecated in v9 and is no longer supported in v10.

There is a migration that typically migrates these cases automatically https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes and https://angular.io/guide/migration-injectable, however it may be that the inherited @Injectable() case is not handled.

Anyway, the resolution here is to add @Injectable() to the abstract base class.

Answer (score 0):

As @Simon_Weaver said you may have a parent class such as :

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
  protected subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.filter(sub => !!sub).forEach(subscription => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

Instead of adding ngOnDestroy to each children you can do that :

```
/* tslint:disable */
@Directive()
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
  protected subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.filter(sub => !!sub).forEach(subscription => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to add a decorator (@Directive) to the base class or remove any Angular interface implemented by the base class. This error started appearing after I upgraded an application to Angular 10. An abstract base class was implementing Angular `OnInit` interface. This class was later extended by actual component classes. Instead of adding an irrelevant decorator, I removed the `OnInit` implementation from the base class that fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

##### Make sure to export the base class

Ran into this again! This time I'd tried to get clever with my base class by deliberately not exporting it.

```
@Directive()
abstract class _SnippetDirective<P>
```

Angular said no!

> The directive SnippetDirective inherits its constructor from
> _SnippetDirective, but the latter does not have an Angular decorator of its own. Dependency injection will not be able to resolve the
> parameters of _SnippetDirective's constructor. Either add a @Directive
> decorator to _SnippetDirective, or add an explicit constructor to
> SnippetDirective.

But of course it DID have a directive. I think what's happening is it doesn't even recognize the base class as being a directive because it doesn't have visibility into it. That's a guess but logically it makes sense.

Exporting the base class fixed it. And also removing 'abstract'