# Can't bind input when using abstract classes (2+ level of hierarchy)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

In my Angular app:

- When a Component uses an Input that is defined in its direct parent (abstract) class, everything works fine.
- When a Component uses an Input that is defined in a 2-levels up parent (abstract) class, the `ng build` or `ng serve` give an error.

For example, I have 4 classes:

```
export abstract class AbstractAComponent {
  @Input() myInput: string;
}
```

```
export abstract class AbstractBComponent extends AbstractAComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.scss']
})
export class OneComponent extends AbstractAComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  templateUrl: './two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two.component.scss']
})
export class TwoComponent extends AbstractBComponent {}
```

This is how I use them:

```
<app-one [myInput]="'value 1'"></app-one>
<app-two [myInput]="'value 2'"></app-two>
```

In a nutshell:
- `@Input() myInput` is defined in `AbstractAComponent`
- `OneComponent` directly extends `AbstractAComponent`
- `TwoComponent` extends `AbstractBComponent` which extends  `AbstractAComponent`

Expected behaviour:
- both `OneComponent` and `TwoComponent` should have `@Input() myInput`

Current behaviour:
- looks like `TwoComponent` doesn't correctly inherit  `@Input() myInput`

and I got the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:2:10 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'myInput' since it isn't a known property of 'app-two'.
1. If 'app-two' is an Angular component and it has 'myInput' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-two' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 9 BaseComponent with @Injectable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116361/angular-9-basecomponent-with-injectable)

Comment: can you use composition instead of inheritance by applying interfaces., I think that could be good to go approach.

Comment: I have the same issue with Angular 12. Tried with @Injectable/@Directive/@Component. None of them work

Answer (score 13):

I initially thought that this was a bug and reported it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35295) where I was actually pointed to the solution by **elvisbegovic**

---

The solution is to add `@Directive()` to your abstract class(es), my in example:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractAComponent {
  @Input() myInput: string;
}
```

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractBComponent extends AbstractAComponent {}
```

Comment: This solution also requires disabling "directive-class-suffix" in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 2):

let try this one:
In `AbstractAComponent`, added `@Directive()`.

```
@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractAComponent {
   @Input() myInput: string;
}
```

And in OneComponent, added `super();` in constructor. This work for me.

```
export class OneComponent extends AbstractAComponent {
   constructor() {
       super();
   }
}
```

Comment: or @Component({})